# Does performance improve when placing a nonclustered index on a field that already has a clustered index?

Tags: sql, indexing, sql-server-2008-r2, clustered-index, non-clustered-index

I executed an update statement along the following lines yesterday:

```
UPDATE MainTable
Set SomeField = SubsetTable.SomeField
where MainTable.MainTableKey = SubsetTable.MainTableKey
```

where `SubsetTable` is a subset of `MainTable` and has the same Primary Key field. `MainTable` has roughly 200m records, `SubsetTable` has 5m records. `MainTableKey` is a GUID.

Both of these table have a clustered index on `MainTableKey`.

When I executed this query the first time it took a whopping 14 hours.

Then I added a non-clustered index to `MainTableKey` on both tables. Now it takes 30 minutes.

Does anyone have any ideas on why the performance gain would be so dramatic?

Comment: What database are you using?  Questions about performance are highly database dependent.

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2. Sorry, just updated the tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet if you look at the execution plans:

The first query is a merge join which involved reading both tables completely.

```
200M rows + 5M rows = 205M rows.
205M rows / 14 hours = 4067 rows per second.
```

The second query is a nested loop join which reads the whole small table and seeks into the large table for each small table row.

```
5M + 5M rows = 10M rows.
10M rows / 40 minutes = 4166rows per second.
```

That these rates are approximately equal, supports my theory about which rows are read.

You don't have to guess:  Run the queries with `SET STATISTICS IO ON`, and/or look at the execution plans.